# Переопределение конструктора

Tags: php, wordpress

Не понимаю, что означает `wfm_fw`

Получается, что теперь конструктор должен будет принимать аргументы?

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'wfm_first_widget' );

function wfm_first_widget(){
    register_widget( 'WFM_Widget' );
}

class WFM_Widget extends WP_Widget{

    function __construct(){
        /*parent::__construct(
            // ID, name, args (description)
            'wfm_fw',
            'Мой первый виджет',
            array( 'description' => 'Описание виджета' )
        );*/
        $args = array(
            'name' => 'Мой первый виджет',
            'description' => 'Описание виджета',
            'classname' => 'wfm-test'
        );
        parent::__construct('wfm_fw', '', $args);
    }

    function widget(){

    }

    function form($instance){
        extract($instance);
        ?>

        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title') ?>">Заголовок:</label>
            <input type="text" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title') ?>" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title') ?>" value="<?php if( isset($title) ) echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>" class="widefat">
        </p>

        <?php
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Из определения конструктора класса `WP_Widget`: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_widget/__construct/

Описание первого параметра.

> Parameters #Parameters
>
> $id_base (string) (Optional) Base ID for the widget, lowercase and
>   unique. If left empty, a portion of the widget's class name will be
>   used Has to be unique.

Т.е по идее это просто уникальный ID виджета. Если поле не заполнять то сгенерируется ID на основе названия класса.